# Convert xecyr cyrillic letters to uppercase

Tags: xetex, cyrillic

How can I convert cyrillic letters defined in xecyr (for example, `\cyra`, `\cyrb`) to uppercase in XeLaTeX? I've tried `\uppercase`, `\MakeUppercase`, `\MakeTextUppercase` and neither of them worked, the text remains in lowercase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xecyr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{cmunrm.otf}[
      BoldFont = cmunbx.otf,
      ItalicFont = cmunti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = cmunbi.otf]

\begin{document}
\uppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\MakeUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\MakeTextUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}
\end{document}
```

`\cyra` is defined as `\DeclareUTFcharacter[\UTFencname]{x0430}{\cyra}`, other letters are defined similarly.

Comment: XeLaTeX expects Unicode input.

Comment: @egreg I know, I should not use these `\cyr*` in XeLaTeX, it's kind of legacy code that I can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the commands to the list used by `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xecyr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{cmunrm.otf}[
      BoldFont = cmunbx.otf,
      ItalicFont = cmunti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = cmunbi.otf]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto\@uclclist{\cyra\CYRA\cyrb\CYRB}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}
\MakeTextUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As requested in the comment here a way to redefine \cyra to a simpler command which works in `\MakeUppercase`. But if could have side-effects, so use it with care. To avoid that it changes all commands defined by xunicode, xunicode is loaded directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{cmunrm.otf}[
      BoldFont = cmunbx.otf,
      ItalicFont = cmunti.otf,
  BoldItalicFont = cmunbi.otf]

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\OldDeclareUTFcharacter\DeclareUTFcharacter
\renewcommand\DeclareUTFcharacter[3][]{%
 \tl_set:Nx\l_tmpa_tl{\tl_tail:n{#2}}
 \tl_set:Nx #3 {\char_generate:nn{"\l_tmpa_tl}{11}} 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff 
\usepackage{xecyr} 
\let\DeclareUTFcharacter\OldDeclareUTFcharacter



\begin{document}
\uppercase{\cyra\cyrb}
\MakeUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}
\MakeTextUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when using your code I have to add a lot of letters manually. I think there is another solution. Is it possible to temporary redefine  `\DeclareUTFcharacter` so that `\cyra` is mapped to `^^^^0430`? The hex digits could be obtained from the first argument (`x0430`).

Comment: I added an edit.

Answer (score 1):

XeLaTeX expects Unicode input, so `polyglossia` doesn't bother to load a correspondence between upper and lower case for the “old style” LICR specifications. However, I understand that legacy documents might have some problems.

A simple workaround is to load the T2A encoding and then immediately override it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,TU]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xecyr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *rm,
  BoldFont       = *bx,
  ItalicFont     = *ti,
  BoldItalicFont = *bi
]

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\MakeTextUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\end{document}
```

You can redefine the LICR to point to a character, say

```
\def\cyra{^^^^0430}
```

This can be done by using the code in `t2aenc.dfu`, which contains line such as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0410}{\CYRA}
```

It's easy, with a good editor, to change that file into `cyrlicr.tex`

```
\newcommand{\RedefineLICR}[2]{\def#2{#1}}

\RedefineLICR{^^^^0401}{\CYRYO}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0402}{\CYRDJE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0404}{\CYRIE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0405}{\CYRDZE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0406}{\CYRII}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0407}{\CYRYI}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0408}{\CYRJE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0409}{\CYRLJE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^040a}{\CYRNJE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^040b}{\CYRTSHE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^040e}{\CYRUSHRT}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^040f}{\CYRDZHE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0410}{\CYRA}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0411}{\CYRB}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0412}{\CYRV}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0413}{\CYRG}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0414}{\CYRD}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0415}{\CYRE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0416}{\CYRZH}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0417}{\CYRZ}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0418}{\CYRI}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0419}{\CYRISHRT}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041a}{\CYRK}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041b}{\CYRL}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041c}{\CYRM}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041d}{\CYRN}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041e}{\CYRO}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^041f}{\CYRP}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0420}{\CYRR}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0421}{\CYRS}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0422}{\CYRT}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0423}{\CYRU}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0424}{\CYRF}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0425}{\CYRH}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0426}{\CYRC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0427}{\CYRCH}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0428}{\CYRSH}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0429}{\CYRSHCH}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042a}{\CYRHRDSN}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042b}{\CYRERY}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042c}{\CYRSFTSN}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042d}{\CYREREV}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042e}{\CYRYU}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^042f}{\CYRYA}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0430}{\cyra}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0431}{\cyrb}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0432}{\cyrv}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0433}{\cyrg}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0434}{\cyrd}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0435}{\cyre}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0436}{\cyrzh}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0437}{\cyrz}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0438}{\cyri}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0439}{\cyrishrt}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043a}{\cyrk}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043b}{\cyrl}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043c}{\cyrm}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043d}{\cyrn}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043e}{\cyro}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^043f}{\cyrp}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0440}{\cyrr}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0441}{\cyrs}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0442}{\cyrt}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0443}{\cyru}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0444}{\cyrf}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0445}{\cyrh}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0446}{\cyrc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0447}{\cyrch}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0448}{\cyrsh}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0449}{\cyrshch}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044a}{\cyrhrdsn}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044b}{\cyrery}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044c}{\cyrsftsn}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044d}{\cyrerev}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044e}{\cyryu}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^044f}{\cyrya}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0451}{\cyryo}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0452}{\cyrdje}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0454}{\cyrie}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0455}{\cyrdze}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0456}{\cyrii}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0457}{\cyryi}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0458}{\cyrje}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0459}{\cyrlje}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^045a}{\cyrnje}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^045b}{\cyrtshe}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^045e}{\cyrushrt}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^045f}{\cyrdzhe}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0490}{\CYRGUP}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0491}{\cyrgup}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0492}{\CYRGHCRS}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0493}{\cyrghcrs}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0496}{\CYRZHDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0497}{\cyrzhdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0498}{\CYRZDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^0499}{\cyrzdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^049a}{\CYRKDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^049b}{\cyrkdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^049c}{\CYRKVCRS}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^049d}{\cyrkvcrs}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a0}{\CYRKBEAK}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a1}{\cyrkbeak}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a2}{\CYRNDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a3}{\cyrndsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a4}{\CYRNG}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04a5}{\cyrng}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04aa}{\CYRSDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04ab}{\cyrsdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04ae}{\CYRY}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04af}{\cyry}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b0}{\CYRYHCRS}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b1}{\cyryhcrs}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b2}{\CYRHDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b3}{\cyrhdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b6}{\CYRCHRDSC}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b7}{\cyrchrdsc}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b8}{\CYRCHVCRS}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04b9}{\cyrchvcrs}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04ba}{\CYRSHHA}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04bb}{\cyrshha}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04c0}{\CYRpalochka}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04d4}{\CYRAE}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04d5}{\cyrae}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04d8}{\CYRSCHWA}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04d9}{\cyrschwa}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04e8}{\CYROTLD}
\RedefineLICR{^^^^04e9}{\cyrotld}
\endinput
```

Note that only the “simple” commands can be used (not the composed ones), and that letters (actually hexadecimal digits) in the first argument must be lowercased. With this file in the working directory, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{xecyr}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}

\setmainfont{cmun}[
  Extension      = .otf,
  UprightFont    = *rm,
  BoldFont       = *bx,
  ItalicFont     = *ti,
  BoldItalicFont = *bi,
]

\input{cyrlicr}

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\MakeTextUppercase{\cyra\cyrb}

\end{document}
```